# Leaflet-side-by-side Question:Dragging button isn't in the middle of the map

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

Trying to use leaflet-side-by-side plugin in Leaflet in Vue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4sl0.png)

```
<template>
  <div id="map" class="map" ref="map">
  </div> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map("map", {
        crs: L.supermap.CRS.TianDiTu_Mercator,
        //center: [42.01, 128.1],//矢量中心
        center: [42.5458, 129.206],
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoom: 12,
        //layers: [this.data[1].children[0].layer, this.data[1].children[1].layer, imgTDT],
        layers: [imgTDT],
        attributionControl: false,
        //全屏组件控制
        fullscreenControl: {
          pseudoFullscreen: false,
        },
        //绘图组件控制 默认填写成false
        drawControl: false
      });
   this.map.invalidateSize()
   this.siderLayer = new L.control.sideBySide([], []).addTo(this.map)
  },
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.map {
  margin: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(0.98,0.98);
}
</style>
```

I tried map.invalidateSize() but it didnt work
https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side/issues/44